# parameters and switches in bash script

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, optionparser

I need to modify one of my scripts. Until now it has two obligatory parameters which point out to version of update and database where this update is going to be applied

```
./script.sh version db_name
```

Now I want to add two new optional parameters, in fact I should call it switches. These switches extend it to :
1.  before install stop (or not) my web server 
2.  install also some new files to filesystem
Both of the returns bool value. All details are inside the script.
So i expect something like:

```
./script.sh version db_name -stopweb  -copyfiles
```

I have figured out **getopts** is suitable command. The problem is how to "join" parameters (obligatory) and switches (optional) together. I really can't get it :( 
Could you give me some hints please.

Comment: you can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash

Comment: right , it is a solution. But my script has been used by several people (and probably called by a few other scripts) so it would be good to keep first two parameters unchanged. So important for me is to keep first two parameter as they are and add optionally two new switches.

Comment: then look at my answer which allows you to do that...

Comment: finally I have found it !    thanks a lot :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, you might upvote it. If my answer solved your question, then accept it as an answer. If not, consider answering your own question with the solution.

Answer (score 5):

You should consider using `getopts`. Here is a sample of what I use for option parsing in my bash scripts:

```
TEMP=$(getopt -o dp:v --long dev,publish:,verbose -- "$@")

# Note the quotes around '$TEMP': they are essential!
eval set -- "$TEMP"

#default values
DEV=0
VERBOSE=
while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -d | --dev ) DEV=1; shift ;;
        -p | --publish ) PUBLISH="$2" ; shift 2;;
        -v | --verbose ) VERBOSE="-v" ; shift ;;
        -- ) if [ -n "$2" ]
            then
                ARGUMENT1=$2
                if [ -n "$3" ]
                then
                    ARGUMENT2=$3
                    if [ -n "$4" ]
                    then
                        shift 3
                        echo "Unexpected options: \"$@\" . exiting."
                        exit 1;
                    fi
                fi
            fi
            shift 2; break;;
        * ) break ;;
    esac
done

# you can add some checks here that ARGUMENT1 and ARGUMENT2 were effectively set, if they are mandatory
```

some features:

- use short and long options
- some options need an argument
- use some optional arguments (one in this case), that doesn't start with `-`

**NOTE** : in order for getopts to be able to distinguish `-dv` being two short options and `--dev` being a long option; all your long options should start with **two hyphens**.

Comment: This is using `getopt(1)` and not `getopts` (they are different things) and while `getopt(1)` supports long options many older versions of `getopt` are broken with options that contain spaces and/or are blank.

Comment: @user3863616 : if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it.